# How to Convert a Maxmind .DAT to CSV?

Tags: geoip, maxmind

Found on the Internet latest base Maxmind GeoIP Organization. But it is in binary form. How can I convert this database to CSV or another format for export to mysql or sqlite? I need to see all the data in a readable form.
p.s. OS - Windows.

Comment: If you purchased the [MaxMind GeoIP Organization database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/organization), a commercial product, you should have access to both a CSV and binary database. I suggest you contact MaxMind support.

Comment: Oh no, this database was purchased not by me. I know that customers have a choice in the type of database, but I have no options.

Comment: Are you asking how to dump a pirated database?

Comment: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/
DBs are for free. They point to this website for processing binary format.